# Linux mint terminal output disappearing

Tags: bash, terminal, output, linux-mint

[image]I'm running a script on terminal and it is supposed to produce a long output, but for some reason the terminal is just showing me the end of the result and I cannot scroll up to see the complete result. Is there a way to save all the terminal instructions and results until I type clear.

The script I'm using has a loop so I need to add the output of the loop if Ill be redirecting the output to a file.

Comment: Hi, would you please add some screen shots?

Comment: You could try increasing the vertical buffer size in your terminal

Comment: Does it need to be on the terminal?  Or can you redirect it `>` into a file?

Comment: @tonymiao I just did

Comment: @mathematician1975 how can I do that please?

Comment: @Jared my script has a loop and when I redirect it only write the last iteration output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your system, the size of the terminal buffer may be fixed and hence you may not be able to scroll far enough to see the full output.

A good alternative would be to output your program/script to a text file using:

`user@terminal # ./nameofprogram > text_file.txt`

Otherwise you will have to find a way to increase the number of lines. In some terminal applications you can go to edit>profiles>edit>scrolling tab and adjust your settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot I did edit>profiles>edit>scrolling tab and adjust your settings. and it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can either redirect the output of your script in a file:

```
 script > file
```

(Be careful to choose a file that does not exist otherwise the content will be erased)

Or you can buffer the output with `less`:

```
 script | less
```

Comment: The script I'm using have a loop so I need to add output every iteration how can I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. If you need all the output, redirection is what you want. You can then consult the file as a text file.

Comment: When I do the redirection I only get the output of the final iteration

Comment: Try with '>>'. Unlike '>', it does not overwrite the file but it append new text on existing text.